# How can I set sheetPeekHeight to the height of an item inside it in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Given the example

```
BottomSheetScaffold(
    sheetContent = {
        LazyColumn(
            state = listState,
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(8.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
        ) {
            items(data.items) {
                Card(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                    Column {
                        Text(text = it.title)
                        Text(text = it.subtitle)
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
                        Text(text = it.image)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    sheetPeekHeight = [...]
) {

}
```

How can I set `sheetPeekHeight` to be, for example, 40% of the first `Card` in the `LazyColumn` within?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
// Need to remember to allow the value changing to mutate the BottomSheet input variable
var peekHeightPx by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

BottomSheetScaffold(
    sheetContent = {
        LazyColumn(
            state = listState,
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(8.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
        ) {
            var index = 0
            items(data.items) {
                Card(modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .onGloballyPositioned {
                        if (index++ == 0) {
                            peekHeightPx = (it.size.height * 0.4f).toInt()
                        }
                    }) {
                    Column {
                        Text(text = it.title)
                        Text(text = it.subtitle)
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
                        Text(text = it.image)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    // If we don't have a value yet, just render it at the default value
    sheetPeekHeight = if (peekHeightPx == 0) {
        BottomSheetScaffoldDefaults.SheetPeekHeight
    } else {
        // The value from onGloballyPositioned is in px and needs to be converted back to a dp value, and 8 needs to be added for the padding and 8 for the spacing between
        (with(LocalDensity.current) { peekHeightPx / density } + 16).dp
    }
) {

}
```

Comment: It will change for every Card in this case

Comment: If the all cards are at the same size, this would work (OP has mentioned nothing about different sizes in items). Otherwise, I have edited my code to match what OP is asking.

Comment: Well dear if all the cards were the same length, why would he specifically mention the first card? We can't make conclusions in our own. Ask for clarification of it's not clear, but do not assert

Comment: Eventually got to a working solution using this answer. I've updated it to compile and include comments about what's going on.